# Is there a way to find out which photos are taking up space in Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I need to recover space due to 1.53 GB of photos taking up my google drive quota. However, before I go ahead and compress these photos using the recover space tool, I want to know which photos I am compressing. I want to know so I can prevent that from happening again-- or perhaps it is going to compress my pixel 2 photos incorrectly?

To the best of my knowledge, I have always had "High Quality" uploads selected and the only "original quality" photos have come from my pixel 2 which should be covered until 2020.

This previous solution: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78812/225552
no longer works due to removal of the method of adding google photos as a folder in google drive.

Related question: [Choose which photos to change from original to high quality](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125103/choose-which-photos-in-google-photos-to-change-from-original-to-high-quality)